# Scala correct syntax to use underscore("_") in function literal with tuple

Tags: scala

I defined a function foo like

```
def foo(f : (Int, Int) => Int) = f(1,2) // just calling with some default vals
```

and can invoke it like

```
foo(_+_)
```

But when i try to use the same way to invoke a function that takes IntPair(custom type) as param then i receive the error

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
```

What is the correct syntax to invoke it

Sample Code

```
type IntPair = (Int, Int)  

def sum(f: (IntPair) => Int): (IntPair) => IntPair = {

def iter(pair: IntPair): IntPair = {
  val n = readLine()
  print(s"$n+")
  if (n != "q") {
    val (total, accum) = pair
    val p: IntPair = (f(n.toInt, total), accum + 1)
    iter(p)
  } else {
    pair
  }
}

   iter
}
```

i can invoke like

```
val f = sum((p : IntPair) => p._1 + p._2) // i want to use here  _ syntax
f((0,0))
```

but not like

```
val f = sum((_._1 + _._2)) //gives error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> def sum(p: ((Int, Int)) => Int) = p((2, 3))
sum: (p: ((Int, Int)) => Int)Int

scala> sum(Function.tupled(_+_))
res4: Int = 5
```

In Scala parameter lists and tuples are not unified, thus you can't simply pass a tuple to a function that expects multiple arguments.

`sum(_._1 + _._2)` means `sum((x,y) => x._1 + y._2)` btw, hence the error.